# about insertion sort improvement in Robert Sedgewick

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I am reading about algorithms by Robert Sedgewick book.

```
public static void sort(Comparable[] a)
{   // Sort a[] into increasing order.
    int N = a.length;
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    { // Insert a[i] among a[i-1], a[i-2], a[i-3]... ..
        for (int j = i; j > 0 && less(a[j], a[j-1]); j--)
            exch(a, j, j-1);
    }
}
```

Above is insertion sort implementation in java. Here author mentiones as improvment as below.

> It is not difficult to speed up insertion sort substantially, by shortening its inner loop to move the larger entries to the right one position rather than doing full exchanges (thus cutting the number of array accesses in half)

I am having difficutly in understanding above improvement. What does author mean by

1. Move large entries to the right one postion rather than full exchanges and how this will reduce array access to half.

Request to example with simple example for better understanding.

Comment: IMO he probably thinks, that if you find the largest number in position i.e. 27 and the array has length 100, you just exchange (switch) the numbers on position 27 and 100 rather than moviing whole array.

Answer (score 5):

I think that he is referring to the fact that you don't need to keep on actually swapping elements, because you will end up repeatedly moving the same element.

For instance, you can cache the value of the `i`-th element initially, and refer just to this in the inner loop:

```
public static <C extends Comparable<C>> void insertionSort(C[] a) {
  for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
    C ithElement = a[i];
    int j = i;
    for (j = i; j > 0 && ithElement.compareTo(a[j - 1]) < 0; --j) {
      // This is "moving the larger entry to the right 1 position"
      a[j] = a[j - 1];
    }
    a[j] = ithElement;
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://ideone.com/IN6RqG)</kbd>